# Changes to the registry do not take effect

Tags: windows, go, winapi

How to make the Settings take effect as soon as possible after setting the registry nic dns information on Windows 7 ?
Can I use the function DhcpNotifyConfigChange? How do I set the parameters?

Comment: The code is written in go.

Comment: Is this helpful --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/setdnsserversearchorder-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration

Comment: Which code? I do not see any.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. However, `DhcpNotifyConfigChange` is a unexposed interface located in dhcpcsvc.dll. And its parameters:

```
BOOL DhcpNotifyConfigChange(
LPWSTR lpwszServerName,     // local machine should be NULL
LPWSTR lpwszAdapterName,    // Adapt name
BOOL bNewIpAddress,     // TRUE indicates changing ip
DWORD dwIpIndex,        // which IP addr, if only 1, it's 0
DWORD dwIpAddress,  // IP addr
DWORD dwSubNetMask,     // mask
int nDhcpAction ); // DHCP, 0 for not change, 1 for enable, 2 for disable DHCP
```